# Test how email looks in gmail and yahoo and other possbile email clients

Tags: webdriver, uiautomation

I am looking for suggestions from the community to solve below mentioned problem statment.

### Problem:

My use case is to check how email looks in gmail,yahoo and even in mobile devices. Outlook and other are out of scope for me.

## Solution 1:

I can use third party services like litmus and other but they are very expensive and moreover my usage is very less.

## Solution 2:

I can built my own tool service this purpose but follow are the chalenges we will come across.

- Need to keep up with UI changes of the Gmail,Yahoo and other services.
- Procuring devices is another challenge

  But i have very good selenium grid cluster including mobile simulators and emulators. The only challenge is to deal with UI changes.

  - Do any open source project which can help me to keep up with UI changes?

Your help is appreciated  in advance.

Regards
KV

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an open-source solution, but since I use MailChimp for sending the emails, I know they offer a tool called [Inbox Inspector](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/test-with-inbox-inspector) which simulates what the email looks like in different clients.

It also might be worthwhile to set up an email account that can be imported into multiple clients using pop3 integration. Then, you could send the email to that account and have a manual tester verify that it looks right in multiple clients. This sort of thing really should be done as a manual test in my opinion, since it's concerned with look-and-feel, which is easiest to judge as a human.